# Update a subscriber in aweber with CURL => session expired

Tags: curl, php, aweber

I am trying to update some custom fields in Aweber using Curl.
When I try to pass postfields, aweber telling me my session has expired. However I can login and do others staffs without this problem.

Maybe the problem come from that there is no form and the button to validate is not a input type submit but a button which there is some js function on? However I look on "network"=> XHR in firebug and the link to send is the same as all parameters in the form.

```
$str = 'data[submit]=1
&data[Lead][prev_stop_status]=0
&unsubscribe_lead=1
&data[Lead]['.$m.'][name]= name
&data[Lead]['.$m.'][email]='.$email.'
&data[Lead]['.$m.'][note]=control panel
&data[Lead]['.$m.'][datum1]=sdfg
&data[Lead]['.$m.'][datum2]=qsdfqsfd
&data[Lead]['.$m.'][datum3]=sdfgf
&data[Lead]['.$m.'][datum4]=zrtert
&data[Lead]['.$m.'][datum5]=dfgdf
&data[Lead]['.$m.'][name2]=sdfgsgf
&message_old=1
&data[Lead]['.$m.'][message]=1001
&sess_token='.$cookie'
```

here $m correspond to the id of lead.

```
$url ='https://www.aweber.com/users/leads/edit/3266822/'.$m;

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.aweber.com/users/leads');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies_file);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$str);  

echo curl_exec($ch);
```

Hope to be enough clear. I would like to post some pic from fireburg to help the understanding but I need more reputation point..

Anyone have an idea ?

edit: here the request by live http header :

POST /users/leads/edit/3266822/59321794 data%5Bsubmit%5D=1&data%5BLead%5D%5Bprev_stop_status%5D=0&unsubscribe_lead=1&data%5BLead%5D%5B59321794%5D%5Bname%5D=blacky&data%5BLead%5D%5B59321794%5D%5Bemail%5D=blackrunnnner%40gmail.com&data%5BLead%5D%5B59321794%5D%5Bnote%5D=+hf&data%5BLead%5D%5B59321794%5D%5Bdatum1%5D=stryrtyy&data%5BLead%5D%5B59321794%5D%5Bdatum2%5D=tttttttttt&data%5BLead%5D%5B59321794%5D%5Bdatum3%5D=sdsdfsdfsdfs&data%5BLead%5D%5B59321794%5D%5Bdatum4%5D=dsfgdsfgd&data%5BLead%5D%5B59321794%5D%5Bdatum5%5D=zzzzzzzzzz&data%5BLead%5D%5B59321794%5D%5Bname2%5D=lmkmlkllllll&message_old=1&data%5BLead%5D%5B59321794%5D%5Bmessage%5D=1&sess_token=d18b8246230780a51e967326cf687009e9cc2d81

and here the header :

https://www.aweber.com/users/leads/edit/3266822/59321794

POST /users/leads/edit/3266822/59321794 HTTP/1.1

Host: www.aweber.com

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0

Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01

Accept-Language: fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

Referer: https://www.aweber.com/users/leads

Content-Length: 619

Cookie: cookie_aweber_referrer_id=99; 
TS8fba11=0db6c7090ec415a2a74f5b65b8aeffc52c7ef8b9018afb4c52e3ecfbbd1b0f791761e990; __utma=121506007.931755370.1390668636.1390668636.1390668636.1; __utmb=121506007.2.10.1390668636; __utmc=121506007; __utmz=121506007.1390668636.1.1.utmgclid=COD4yK_kmbwCFTCWtAod7U4ApA|utmccn=(not%20set)|utmcmd=(not%20set)|utmctr=aweber; _ga=GA1.2.931755370.1390668636; AppCookie[cookie_support]=supported; TS8fba11_29=c7dae97d9386c44fe3317a881058edd12c7ef8b9018afb4c00000000000000000052e3eb6c; __ctxpop=1; AUTORESPSID=d18b8246230780a51e967326cf687009e9cc2d81; AppCookie[customer]=1; AppCookie[curlis]=teststeli; kvcd=1390668716223; km_ai=Km0KWrpCZfFJ0Q7ArZebQRtwxVE%3D; km_uq=; km_vs=1; km_lv=1390668716; km_ni=836900; ki_u=9560e337-a9a3-16a1-44d0-1060ea2aa10c; ki_t=1390668681618%3B1390668681618%3B1390668681618%3B1%3B1

Connection: keep-alive

Pragma: no-cache

Cache-Control: no-cache

data%5Bsubmit%5D=1&data%5BLead%5D%5Bprev_stop_status%5D=0&unsubscribe_lead=1&data%5BLead%5D%5B59321794%5D%5Bname%5D=blacky&data%5BLead%5D%5B59321794%5D%5Bemail%5D=blackrunnnner%40gmail.com&data%5BLead%5D%5B59321794%5D%5Bnote%5D=+hf&data%5BLead%5D%5B59321794%5D%5Bdatum1%5D=stryrtyy&data%5BLead%5D%5B59321794%5D%5Bdatum2%5D=tttttttttt&data%5BLead%5D%5B59321794%5D%5Bdatum3%5D=sdsdfsdfsdfs&data%5BLead%5D%5B59321794%5D%5Bdatum4%5D=dsfgdsfgd&data%5BLead%5D%5B59321794%5D%5Bdatum5%5D=zzzzzzzzzz&data%5BLead%5D%5B59321794%5D%5Bname2%5D=lmkmlkllllll&message_old=1&data%5BLead%5D%5B59321794%5D%5Bmessage%5D=1&sess_token=d18b8246230780a51e967326cf687009e9cc2d81

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Sat, 25 Jan 2014 17:08:56 GMT

p3p: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"

Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT

Last-Modified: Sat, 25 Jan 2014 17:08:57 GMT

Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, No-Cache

Pragma: no-cache, No-Cache

Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent

Content-Encoding: gzip

Content-Length: 164

Keep-Alive: timeout=3, max=100

Connection: Keep-Alive

Content-Type: text/plain

Set-Cookie:TS8fba11=75ec74303092e39b0609f650ba7394ad2c7ef8b9018afb4c52e3efa8bd1b0f791761e990; Path=/

Comment: Do you get a redirect? 'cause in that case you might also want to specify a cookiejar instead of only a cookiefile. Also: in your posted example you are adding newlines to the data, what happens if you make the whole post string one line?

Comment: How can I know if I get a redirect ? I tried also to specify a cookiejar but the result is same. Yes I tried to make all in 1 line also.

Comment: Disable follow location temporarily & include the header in the output, that'll tell you a lot already. Then again: you might ask the folks at Awerber what goes wrong, or see if you can do what you want with their API.

Comment: Yes maybe I will check their API if I don't find out..

Comment: are you getting this variable correctly  `&sess_token='.$cookie'` ?

Comment: Hello, yes  cause I use it for connection and other staff and this work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
<?php
//debug - remove in production!
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//debug end

$str = 'data[submit]=1
&data[Lead][prev_stop_status]=0
&unsubscribe_lead=1
&data[Lead]['.$m.'][name]= name
&data[Lead]['.$m.'][email]='.$email.'
&data[Lead]['.$m.'][note]=control panel
&data[Lead]['.$m.'][datum1]=sdfg
&data[Lead]['.$m.'][datum2]=qsdfqsfd
&data[Lead]['.$m.'][datum3]=sdfgf
&data[Lead]['.$m.'][datum4]=zrtert
&data[Lead]['.$m.'][datum5]=dfgdf
&data[Lead]['.$m.'][name2]=sdfgsgf
&message_old=1
&data[Lead]['.$m.'][message]=1001
&sess_token='.$cookie'

$url ='https://www.aweber.com/users/leads/edit/3266822/'.$m;
$cookies_file = "/tmp/cookie.txt";    

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.aweber.com/users/leads');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies_file);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies_file);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $str);  
$server_output =  curl_exec($ch);

if ($server_output == "OK") { 
    echo "Post OK";
} else { 
    echo "Post NOT OK \n";
    echo $server_output;
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I get POST NOT OK. What that's mean ? The url is not good or the postfields ?

Comment: besides that, what errors did you get ? I've updated the answer and add `$cookies_file = "/tmp/cookie.txt";  , try it again.

Comment: I didn't get any error. Just aweber telling me my session has expired. And my path for $cookies_file is __DIR__.'/cookies.txt' and I declare it already above in my script

Comment: lets try this, install `live http headers` addon for firefox, activate it and manually login to aweber. copy and past the headers to your answer. this may help us to understand where the error is.

Comment: I updated my answer. The problem is I can get the page and see the form with old field but fields aren't modified and the content field I send by url aren't considered.